# Why I keep on getting property undefined when it is declared already?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

My problem is about the theme where I need to toggle it but I'm getting trouble with the types. I'm not sure if it something with my typescript configuration or with my code.

I tried to reproduce the problem [in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-river-7qyk8) but there's no error showing up. But I will explain how it appears on my local machine.

In my `hooks.ts` file `line 12` I'm getting an error saying `type` does not exist even though there is.

```
 TS2339: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'PaletteOptions | undefined'.
```

And on `line 24` I'm getting error saying

```
[0]       TS2345: Argument of type '{ palette: { type: string; } | { type: string; primary?: SimplePaletteColorOptions | Partial<Color> | undefined; secondary?: SimplePaletteColorOptions | Partial<Color> | undefined; ... 9 more ...; getContrastText?: ((background: string) => string) | undefined; }; ... 10 more ...; zIndex?: Partial<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<ThemeOptions>'.
[0]   Type '{ palette: { type: string; } | { type: string; primary?: SimplePaletteColorOptions | Partial<Color> | undefined; secondary?: SimplePaletteColorOptions | Partial<Color> | undefined; ... 9 more ...; getContrastText?: ((background: string) => string) | undefined; }; ... 10 more ...; zIndex?: Partial<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ThemeOptions'.
[0]     Types of property 'palette' are incompatible.
[0]       Type '{ type: string; } | { type: string; primary?: SimplePaletteColorOptions | Partial<Color> | undefined; secondary?: SimplePaletteColorOptions | Partial<Color> | undefined; error?: SimplePaletteColorOptions | ... 1 more ... | undefined; ... 8 more ...; getContrastText?: ((background: string) => string) | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'PaletteOptions | undefined'.
[0]         Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'PaletteOptions'.
[0]           Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
[0]             Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"light" | "dark" | undefined'.
```

I'm not sure if it is because I use `ThemeOptions` as the type of my custom type in `theme.ts` though I'm not getting error on that file. But setting it to `Theme` type doesn't remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

It cant recognize any string to a PaletteType:

```
import { PaletteType } from '@material-ui/core';

const updatedTheme = {
  ...theme,
  palette: {
    ...theme.palette,
    type: (type === "light" ? "dark" : "light") as PaletteType
  }
};
```